# HTML5 Video player controls are not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

***Code Snippet : Creating the video player element in the javascript on page load***

```
videoplayer = document.createElement("video");
videoplayer.setAttribute("id","myVideoPlayer");
videoplayer.setAttribute("controls","controls");
videoplayer.setAttribute("style","display:none");
videoplayer.setAttribute("width","200");
videoplayer.setAttribute("height", "200");
videosource = document.createElement("source");
videosource.type = "video/mp4";

videoplayer.appendChild(videosource);

containerDiv.appendChild(videoplayer);
```

***and on user click event I am changing the source of video player***

```
videoplayer = document.getElementById("myVideoPlayer");


var videosource= videoplayer.getElementsByTagName('source');
videosource = videosource[0]
videosource.src = "my video url comes here";
videosource.type = "video/mp4";

videoplayer.pause();    
videoplayer.load();
videoplayer.play();
```

***If I do the forward and backward its still starts from where we left.***

Comment: More detailed code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the src of the videoplayer element, not the videosource element.

So, for you the code will be

```
videoplayer.setAttribute("src", "your video path");
```

Comment: Not working. I am able to play video but i cant do forward and backward.

Comment: How are you going forward and backward? By using the video timeline?

Comment: By using the video control.(Seek/Cursor which is present in the video control ribbon)

Comment: You'll need to add more detailed code I think. Maybe a fiddle